# Condensing a large formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I was wondering if anyone could enlighten me on a way to condense/shorten this formula:

`=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Kirkintilloch",B2)),"BRN01",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Tweacher",B2)),"BRN01",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Lenzie",B2)),"BRN01",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Bishopbrigg",B2)),"BRN03",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Torrance",B2)),"BRN03",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Bearsden",B2)),"BRN04",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Milngavie",B2)),"BRN04")))))))`

Column B will contain an address which will be from one of these seven towns. 
The reason I didn't do an `IF` then `Lookup` was that the result I want to return is not unique, I.e. `Kirkintilloch` & `Torrance` both need to return a result of `BRN01`.

If it's not possible to simplify this then no worries. It would just save me a lot of work in a larger piece of work with many more possible outcomes.

Comment: Better put some sample data and your desired output then explain logic to gain that output. Then we may think a different approach/formula for you.

Comment: Is there more than just the town name in a cell?

Comment: If I read your question, and look at your formula I come to wonder why you do `ISNUMBER(SEARCH(...))` If you simply want to return a code for a city name just check for the cityname, and return the code.

Comment: I get why you do `ISNUMBER(SEARCH())` now, but it would have been better if you included that in your question. B2 simply contains a complete adress, streetname (zipcode) city, so searching for city in that string, and if it is found it will return a number.

Answer (score 0):

This is an array formula - confirm it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> while still in the formula bar:

`=INDEX(Towns,SMALL(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(INDEX(Towns,0,2),B2)),INDEX(Towns,0,1)),1),3)`

Breaking this down:

First you need to create a named range (I called mine "Towns") that contains the array of an index, the town name and the desired return `"BRN**"` (you could make this a simple range and just reference that but I entered the actual array by selecting the range in formula, highlighting it and using F9 to calculate)

[image]

Now that you have this array, I use Index providing 0 for the row argument to return all rows so that I can equate against just a single column at a time.

`IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(INDEX(Towns,0,2),B2)),INDEX(Towns,0,1))`

As this is an array formula, each row is assessed individually and the results (first column when a match is found - index of the array) returned as an array, like so: `{FALSE;FALSE;3;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE}`

I then use `SMALL()` to catch the lowest number or the first match to feed another index for the third column.

[image]